nixos live usb boot stuck at Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok
When trying to boot from a NixOS live usb with 23.11, gnome for x86_64:
On a Asus C236 WSI Motherboard with this BIOS:
$ ls -l /sys/class/dmi/id/bios*                                                                                                                                                 
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 09:59 /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_date
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 09:59 /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_release
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 09:01 /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_vendor
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Apr 24 09:56 /sys/class/dmi/id/bios_version
$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/bios*                                                                                                                                                   
10/21/2015
5.11
American Megatrends Inc.
P1.00

boot up screen gets stuck at first line with:
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok


At the NixOS boot menu, press Tab to edit the kernel command line. Add edd=off to the beginning and press Enter to load it.
See screenshot:

